# ROS Answers SE migration: publish array

Tags: ros, array, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi at all,

easy question (or at least i hope so): how can I write a publisher which publishes an float64array? the problem is, i'm quite new to c++ so i don't understand all of the lines in the tutorial, where a string is published.

thx in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42362/publish-array/) by [shane](https://answers.ros.org/users/3039/shane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Whereever the string message would be filled, when you fill the array, you would use push_back as ROS translates the arrays to c++ vectors.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1